# Как передать параметр windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Есть написанная служба. Из программы запускаю эту службу. Как передать ей параметр, строковую переменную?
Можно ли в этот метод как-то передать?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{}
```

Comment: Все, разобрался. Ответ простой, конечно - можно.

Comment: Ответ с решением напиши.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В методе, который запускает сервис:

```
 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Имя сервиса");
   string[] args = new string[1];
   rgs[0] = path_XML;
   sc.Start(args);
```

В самом сервисе принимаем:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
            // TODO: Add code here to start your service. 
            path_XML = args[0];
    }
```